# Why is my new C# Switch Expression Not Compiling?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I am trying to get up to speed on the new switch expressions.  Here is what I am trying to write:

```
email.EmailTypeId switch
{
     (int)Enums.EmailType.Booked => ProcessBookedMessage(email, document),
     (int)Enums.EmailType.BookingRequest => ProcessBookingRequest(email, document),
     (int)Enums.EmailType.Message => ProcessMessage(email, document),
     (int)Enums.EmailType.Remainder => ProcessReminder(email, document),
     (int)Enums.EmailType.ReminderSoon => ProcessReminder(email, document)
 }
```

This looks reasonable to me, but it give a compile time error, saying that a semicolon should be added at the end.

But when I do that, i get another error message: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: And the next error would be that a "default" branch (denoted by `_ =>`) is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch expressions are meant to produce a value, and that value should also "go somewhere".

The syntax should be `var x = email.EmailTypeId switch { ..... };` or `return email.EmailTypeId switch { ..... };`.

Also note that the `Process....` methods **must** all return a value (all of the same type).

Maybe you meant to use a *[switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement)* instead:

```
switch(email.EmailType)
{
     case EmailType.Booked:
         ProcessBookedMessage(email, document);
         break;    
     case EmailType.Message:
         ...
         break;
     ...etc...
     default:
         ...
         break;
}
```

Comment: Please check this new syntax: https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/new-switch-syntax-with-c-8-0-bfee2622de91.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the problem is simple. Your `switch` statement is a new syntax, added in C# 8.0 and since you try to use it in a 7.0 version it yields an error.

Example:

```
public static NewSwitch FromRainbow(Color color) =>
color switch
{
    Color.Red    => new NewSwitch(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00),
    Color.Orange => new NewSwitch(0xFF, 0x7F, 0x00),
    Color.Yellow => new NewSwitch(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00),
    Color.Green  => new NewSwitch(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00),
    Color.Blue   => new NewSwitch(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF),
    Color.Indigo => new NewSwitch(0x4B, 0x00, 0x82),
    Color.Violet => new NewSwitch(0x94, 0x00, 0xD3),
    _            => throw new ArgumentException(message: "invalid color", paramName: nameof(color)),
};
```

Taken from https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/new-switch-syntax-with-c-8-0-bfee2622de91

[image]

Solution: either use the old syntax, or upgrade your .NET and C#.

Comment: The question is tagged `.NET 7` which uses `C# 11`. So "or upgrade your .NET and C#" is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up using. As Peter points out, you must return something in a switch `expression`, so I just returned the method to be run. Pretty clever if you ask me.

```
 Action<EmailNotification, HtmlDocument> methodToRun = email.EmailTypeId switch
 {
      Enums.EmailType.Booked => ProcessBookedMessage,
      Enums.EmailType.BookingRequest => ProcessBookingRequest,
      Enums.EmailType.Message => ProcessMessage,
      Enums.EmailType.Remainder => ProcessReminder,
      Enums.EmailType.ReminderSoon => ProcessReminder,
      Enums.EmailType.Unsupported => ProcessUnsupported,
      _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
  };
  methodToRun(email, document);
```